# Login failed with case-insensitive username

Tags: kylin

Username is case-insensitive in login authentication but case-sensitive in hbase metadata

> org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.WriteConflictException:
>   Overwriting conflict /user/Admin, expect old TS 1536031295060, but it
>   is 0 
>   org.apache.kylin.storage.hbase.HBaseResourceStore.checkAndPutResourceImpl(HBaseResourceStore.java:325)
>   org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.checkAndPutResourceCheckpoint(ResourceStore.java:323)
>   org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.putResource(ResourceStore.java:308)
>   org.apache.kylin.common.persistence.ResourceStore.putResource(ResourceStore.java:287)
>   org.apache.kylin.metadata.cachesync.CachedCrudAssist.save(CachedCrudAssist.java:192)
>   org.apache.kylin.rest.security.KylinUserManager.update(KylinUserManager.java:122)
>   org.apache.kylin.rest.service.KylinUserService.updateUser(KylinUserService.java:85)
>   org.apache.kylin.rest.security.KylinAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KylinAuthenticationProvider.java:117)
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174)
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199)
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:180)
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)

Answer (score 0):

This bug will be fixed in kylin 2.5.1, which is about to release.

Please refer to this: https://github.com/apache/kylin/pull/235
If you are using the older version, you can run the following command to bypass this issue.

*$KYLIN_HOME/bin/metastore.sh remove /user*

I hope that will help you!